# Orthogonal trajectory to the family of Parabolas.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: The family of curves $y = gs(x), s ∈ S ⊆ R$, is called the orthogonal
trajectories to another given family of curves $y = ft(x), t ∈ T ⊆ R$, if always that a function $gs$ and function $ft$
intersect each other, their respective tangent lines
at the intersection point are perpendicular.
(a) Find the orthogonal trajectories to the family of parabolas $y = αx^2
, α \in R $ numbers

My Work:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x\alpha$$

$$dy = (2x\alpha)dx$$

Because I want their trajectory to always be perpendicular I replace $(2x\alpha)$ by $-\frac{1}{2x\alpha}$ and then solve.

$$dy = -\frac{1}{2x\alpha} dx$$

$$y = -\frac{ln(x)}{2\alpha} + C$$

Is this correct?

Furthermore, I attempted to solve this problem through another method which did not yield me positive results, perhaps someone could help me finish the idea. I began the problem by stating letting $\alpha = 1$ then

$$y = αx^2 \rightarrow y=x^2$$

because $\alpha$ can be seen as a scalar its role does not play a part on finding anything orthogonal. Next

$$(x, x^2) \cdot (a,b) = 0 $$

$$ ax + bx^2 = 0$$

$$ a = -bx$$

$$(x,x^2) \cdot (-bx,x) = 0$$

Here is where I run into trouble

$$(-bx,x) = 0 $$

$$ bx = x $$

$$b = 1$$ .

I appreciate any feedback/answers/hints. Thank you for your time.

Comment: $α$ can *not* be seen as a scalar that does not play a part in finding anything orthogonal. It changes the slope of the parabola and everything orthogonal to it. The first method is also wrong, as $α$ depends on $x,y$ implicitly. You should first eliminate $α$ using the equation of the family, $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x\frac{y}{x^2}$, and *then* change to the negative reciprocal $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x^2}{2xy}$ and solve, see [How to find the orthogonal trajectories](https://www.kristakingmath.com/blog/how-to-find-orthogonal-trajectories).

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for your input. I'll go over it and fix it